# Restructuring of an if

Tags: c

Can you help me rearrange this code? cLion suggests a warning to the accolade of the first if [Clang-Ti dy: Repeated branch in conditional chain], I do not understand why. P.S I try to compare 2 calendar dates, to later set the maximum date and the minimum date.(d - day, m - mounth and y - year).

```
if (d1.y < d2.y) {
    return -1;
} else if (d1.y == d2.y && d1.m < d2.m) {
    return -1;
} else if (d1.y == d2.y) {
    if (d1.m == d2.m) {
        if (d1.d < d2.d) {
            return -1;
        }
    }
} else {
    return 1;
}
return 0;
```

Comment: What is the exact wording of the warning?

Comment: Please edit your question to show the warning(s) as text verbatim.  Also note that the final `return 0;` statement is unreachable.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Clang-Tidy: Repeated branch in conditional chain

Comment: @RobertHarvey I don't understand what this should look like

Comment: @G.M. If I pull out return 0; I get the error Non-void function does not return a value in all control paths

Comment: @kammy That's just because the compiler fails to detect the fact that code execution can never get that far.

Comment: @G.M.: The final `return 0;` is reachable. Inside the `else if(d1.y == d2.y)`, the code returns only if `d1.m == d2.m` is true and `d1.d < d2.d` is true. Otherwise, it falls through.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Are you sure?  The `else` appears to be matched with the initial `if(d1.y < d2.y){` (although the indentation is misleading).  I may have misread it though.

Comment: I don't think the code does what you hope it does: if `d1.y == d2.y` and `d1.m > d2.m` the code returns `0`, but the dates are not equal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are numerous ways to write this code. Here is one that attempts to show the comparisons clearly:

```
//  If years differ, return comparison based on that.
if      (d1.y < d2.y)
    return -1;
else if (d1.y > d2.y)
    return +1;

//  Otherwise, if months differ, return comparison based on that.
else if (d1.m < d2.m)
    return -1;
else if (d1.m > d2.m)
    return +1;

//  Otherwise, if days differ, return comparison based on that.
else if (d1.d < d2.d)
    return -1;
else if (d1.d > d2.d)
    return +1;

//  Otherwise, all components are equal, so return equality.
else
    return  0;
```

Answer (score 1):

If I had to guess, your `d1` and `d2` objects are "dates". Hence, the members, `y` (year), `m` (month), and `d` (day). And your comparison logic seems to test if d1 is a later date than d2.  I'm guessing for a sort routine like qsort.

Hence, a quick conversion to integer might be cleaner.

```
long date1 = (d1.y << 16) | (d1.m << 8) | (d1.d);
long date2 = (d2.y << 16) | (d2.m << 8) | (d2.d);
```

Then you can test like this:

```
if (date1 == date2) return 0;
if (date1 > date2) return 1;
return -1;
```

But wait for it... you can even avoid `if` statements like this by returning a mixed algebraic and boolean statement:

```
return (date1 > date2)*1 + (date1 < date2) * (-1);
```

But if this is for a qsort like comparison function where you can return anything greater than 0 for `d1>d2`, and anything less than zero for `d1<d2`, then you can simply say this:

```
return date1-date2;
```